# Well-definedness of the integral of a simple function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A simple function $f:X \to \mathbb{C}$ on a measure space $(X,\mu)$ is a measurable function with a finite range. Let $\mathrm{ran}(f) = \{z_1,\dots,z_n\}$. Then the **standard representation** of $f$ is given by $$f = \sum_{k = 1}^n z_k \chi_{f^{-1}(\{z_k\})}$$ according to the book by Folland. He defines the $\mu$-integral of a nonnegative simple function $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ as $$\int_X f d\mu := \sum_{k = 1}^n z_k \mu\left(f^{-1}(\{z_k\})\right)$$ However, for example Cohn or Elstrodt (and my professor) now proove, that this integral is independent of the representation of $f$. I think, if we do define the standard representation like Folland, this is an unnecessary task, since the standard representation is unique. Am I right?

Comment: It's not clear that that this integral only depends on $f$ from the definition, but if it were then it would be clear that it didn't matter how $f$ were represented.

Comment: Even though the standard representation is unique, it would not be satisfactory to define the integral in terms of it, unless every other representation gave the $same$ result. Hence, the proofs in Cohn, et al-

Comment: @Chilango Ah I see what you mean. But if we define it invoking the standard representation it is not mandatory (but nice to know, or satisfacting) to show the independence of the representation. In Cohn, et. al it is called well-definedness, but the main point here is (defining it with the standard representation), that it is already well-defined. Thanks.

Comment: I think the main point is that one may use the standard representation to define the integral precisely because $any$ two representations give the same result. Were this not the case, a satisfactory theory could not be developed. So, at some point, you need to prove the independence, much in the same way that $1/2$ for example is simply a representative of an equivalence class of ordered pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice answer to this question can be found in the Real Analysis book by Stein and Shakarchi, page 50-52.